# When I tried to modify the IP address using adb shell commands, the Android device stopped responding

Tags: android, genymotion, adb

I tested on a Genymotion emulator, the ROM is Android 8.0
When I call "ifconfig eth0", I can receive the returned result normally.

But when I want to modify the IP address, I call "ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.173 netmask 255.255.255.0"
The device stopped responding and nothing happens when I click on the Android emulator. The adb command no longer responds. I can't run APP through Android Studio (it prompts that the device cannot be connected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eth0 interface settings must NOT be changed, or this will break communication between Genymotion and VirtualBox. What is your use case?

Comment: My use case is to modify the IP address of an embedded device equipped with Android, but it is troublesome to connect to ADB, so I want to use Genymotion to debug. I have given up Genymotion now and started troublesome debugging.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this with Genymotion "out of the box". One possible option is to set Genymotion Desktop network mode to Bridge (https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/latest/03_Virtual_devices.html#configure-a-virtual-device) and let a DHCP server handle the device addressing, but I can't guarantee the result.